# How can I integrate outlook 365 with sendgrid

Tags: office365, sendgrid, email

My company has outlook 365 exchange mail server and I am trying to integrate it with SendGrid.
There isnt an official document on how to do it, as you may see from SendGrid's page:
http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Mail_Servers/index.html
They only have exchange 2010 in there, but not 365.

If you integrated 365 with SendGrid, please share your knowledge.
Otherwise, if you integrated 365 with a different service, recommendations and guide is also appreciated.

Thanks
Adam

Comment: I'm confused by what product you are using. Outlook and exchange are different things; one is a mail server, one is a client. Can you link me to the product page for the system you are asking your question about?

Comment: hi brand, i'm trying to integrate the mail server with sendgrid, not my client. we have online hosted exchange server

Comment: Can you please provide a link with information about the hosted exchange server you are using?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/microsoft-exchange-online-email-for-business-FX103739072.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have found the information you are after. Unfortunately I can't help you go through the steps because I don't have access to an Exchange Online account, but hopefully these resources will solve your problem.

The reason there isn't information about this in the Exchange Online docs is that it's actually something that needs to be done in Forefront.

Here are the basic steps:

[Configure a Send Connector in Forefront](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/158/p/83954/329631.aspx#329631)

> In Exchange Online/Office 365, mailboxes are protected by Forefront Online Protection for Exchange (FOPE). If you are an Office 365 E plan user, please refer to the following steps:
>
> 1. Log in to Office 365 MOP page with admin account.
> 2. Click Manage under Exchange tab.
> 3. Click Manage My Organization->Mail Control->Rules, click the link "Configure IP safelisting, perimeter message tracing, and e-mail policies", then you will be directed to the FOPE website.
> 4. Configure the connectors.

And here is an [in-depth article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430178.aspx) describing the same workflow you are after. Just swap "on-premises server" for "SendGrid."